# Add Asset for Auto Scale in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing Auto Scaling using SoftLayer java client. 
Can you give me a guide or sample code to add Assets using JAVA API?
Please refer to the attached picture. 
[image: AddAsset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next java script can be used to add an asset to SoftLayer Auto Scale:

```
/**
* This script creates a SoftLayer_Scale_Asset_Virtual_Guest for a 
* SoftLayer_Scale_Group
*
* Important manual pages:
* @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Scale_Asset_Virtual_Guest/createObject
* @see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Scale_Asset_Virtual_Guest
*
* @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/wiki/index.php/License>
* @author SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
*/
package SoftLayer_Java_Scripts.Examples;

import com.softlayer.api.*;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.asset.virtual.Guest;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class CreateScaleAssetVirtualGuest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
      // Fill with your valid data here.
      String user = "set me";
      String apiKey = "set me";   
      long scaleGroupId = 112233;
      long virtualGuestId = 44556677;

      // Creating a client and the service that’s going to call the API method.
      ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(user, apiKey);
      Guest.Service service = Guest.service(client);

      // A SoftLayer_Scale_Asset_Virtual_Guest container used to store the scale group id and
      // the virtual guest id that’s going to be the new asset.
      Guest assetVirtualGuestTemplate = new Guest();
      assetVirtualGuestTemplate.setScaleGroupId(scaleGroupId);
      assetVirtualGuestTemplate.setVirtualGuestId(virtualGuestId);

      try
      {
        Guest assetVirtualGuest = service.createObject(assetVirtualGuestTemplate);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(assetVirtualGuest));
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println("Script failed, review the next message for further details: " + e); 
      }
    }
}
```

The next links could also help you:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Scale_Asset_Virtual_Guest/createObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Scale_Asset_Virtual_Guest